# datapicker reactjs inout date format

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

i need format date datapicker react js

```
<div className="caja-select">
     <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.fechaInicial}
          onChange={this.onChangeFilterFechaInicial}
          locale="es"
          dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      />
</div>
```

[image]

press enter take the date format dd/ MM / yyyy

Comment: what is the datatype of this.state.fechaInicial??

Comment: fechaInicial: new Date()

Answer (score 1):

you should set your state like this

```
 this.state = {fechaInicial: moment()};
```

and use date formate like this

```js
<DatePicker selected={this.state.date}
                    onChange={this.dateChanged} dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
```

to used moment() you should install momentjs also. [here](https://momentjs.com/)

check demo [here](https://codepen.io/jualahmed/pen/GRJMbWx)

Comment: I already tried, but I still have the same error. entry 01012020 and the datepicker component is displayed as 01/01/101202

Comment: `onChangeFilterFechaInicial = date => {
        const newDate = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
        console.log(newDate);
        const myDate = new Date(date);
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 365);
        this.setState({
            fechaInicial: date,
            fechaFinalMaxConsultaNura: myDate
        });
    };`